# How to retrieve a specific cookie value if it has multiple values using JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I'm using jquery and I was wondering how do I retrieve a certain cookie value if I have multiple values, something like this:

```
$.cookie("name",[email,loc], { path: '/', expires: 60 });
```

How do I retrieve loc value?

Note: email and loc are set as variables.

I know you can get values by

```
$.cookie("name");
```

but i just want loc, not email and loc.

Comment: We need to know which cookie plugin you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$.cookie("name")[1]`.
But nobody can tell you for sure without knowing which plugin you are using (it has to do some serializing/deserializing since cookies only contain plaintext - no arrays, objects, etc).

Comment: This did not work for me, I'm using this one 1.0.x http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie if i can't do this, then i guess the only way would to create another cookie just for that value, correct?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like jQuery's plugin. See the json section of https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.md on multiple values. You'd have to use curly instead of list brackets.

On the other hand you could parse the string yourself or create several cookies.